# What programming languages does the Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner support?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm learning about Spring Cloud Contract and have a question regarding the supported languages. While writing SCC Stub runner based contract tests the documentation seems to imply that we're supporting tests written in either JUnit or Spock.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.2.x/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_stub_runner.html

Can we use the Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner only for Java / Groovy languages or does it support other languages as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the blog post https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world and the documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#flows-provider-non-jvm where we explain the workflows for non jvm apps. Here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl you can find the list of supported contract formats. Please always read the documentation before filing a question.

Comment: Thanks for referencing this! I remember reading about it supporting non-JVM apps somewhere but somehow missed this.